# /app/run.sh: line 7: java: command not found while running docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I've created an image in docker and having `/app/run.sh: line 7: java: command not found`
 while trying to run this using `sudo docker run com.project.question/question:1.0.0`
.Here's my run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE:-"local-docker"}
GIT_BRANCH_LABEL=${GIT_BRANCH_LABEL:-"develop"}

java -jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -    Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE} -    Dgit.config.active.branch=${GIT_BRANCH_LABEL} -Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${APP_JAR_NAME}.jar
```

Here's my `DockerFile`
    FROM openjdk:8u121-jdk-alpine
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

```
ENV APP_JAR_NAME question

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl apt-utils wget unzip
RUN rm -rf /var/chache/apk/*
RUN mkdir /app

ADD ${APP_JAR_NAME}.jar /app/
COPY run.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]
CMD ["/app/run.sh"]
```

I'm having following images in my docker 
[image]
I'm looking for the solution for hours but didn't find anything useful. Please help me figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following doesn't merge images, it pulls 2 images and then continues the build based off the second image, Ubuntu, which doesn't include Java:

```
FROM openjdk:8u121-jdk-alpine
FROM ubuntu:18.04
```

You probably want the `stretch` based openjdk image, rather than Alpine, and then remove the second `FROM` line.

Comment: Thanks,do I need to install open-jdk using `DockerFile`? I'm a newbie in creating docker images

Comment: would you please elaborate the difference between `stretch` based openjdk image and oracle jdk. Thanks

Comment: Stretch is based on Debian, which Ubuntu is derived from.